# how to add custom html attributes in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i want to replicate this html code in vue from [this site](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/handle-credential-responses-js-functions#handle_credential_response) it works well when im using plain html & inline js

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
</div>
<script>
  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
     // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
     // to decode the credential response.
     const responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);

     console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
     console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
     console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
     console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
     console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
     console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
  }
</script>
```

but the problem is when i want to make `data-callback` attributes available in my vue code,
my attempt is like the code below, unfortunatelly the console log doesnt trigger anything

```
<script setup>
const handleCallback = (res) => {
   console.log({res}) // doesnt run
}
</script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     :data-callback="handleCallback">
</div>
```

I also tried using `@data-callback=` and `:data-callback=`
how can i make html attributes callback in vue?

Comment: Have you included Google JS code?

Comment: you mean this code? it already loaded <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>

Comment: I think Google callback is calling function window.handleCredentialResponse, so plain html & js will work, in vue's world, the function handleCredentialResponse is not under window object, so the callback is calling an undefined function. You can try this library for login with google. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-google-login

Answer (score -1):

Try binding a prop with the attribute. Using `watch` to hook the prop.

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     :data-client-id="data_client_id">
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: ['data_client_id'],
  data: {},
  watch: { 
     data_client_id: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
          console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
     },
  }
});
</script>
```